# jquery Sortable connectWith calls the update method twice 

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

In the code below the update function gets called twice when an item is moved from list `sortable1` to `sortable2`. Though I need to call that function only once:

```
$("#sortable1 tbody, #sortable2 tbody").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable tbody',
    helper: fixHelper,
    handle : '.handle',
    update : function () {
        var order = $('#sortable1 tbody').sortable('serialize');
    }    
}).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 63):

Answer from: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortables-update-callback-and-connectwith

```
update: function(e,ui) {
    if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: It worth noting `this` is the interesting value here. `update` is fired twice namely by the list where the element is dragged out and the list the element was dragged into. `ui.item.parent()` refers to the parent of the dragged element. If you wonder why this works :)

Answer (score 14):

Stefan's answer was good, but it doesn't mention one more piece of the puzzle, so here it is - in case someone (like me) doesn't get it right away. This should make it possible for you to handle it all in the `update()` function and to not have to mess with `receive()` (which will get triggered *only* when inter-container movements happen):

```
update: function(e,ui) {
    if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
        if (ui.sender !== null) {
          // the movement was from one container to another - do something to process it
          // ui.sender will be the reference to original container
        } else {
          // the move was performed within the same container - do your "same container" stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
update: function(e,ui) {
    if (!ui.sender) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work because then you're not seeing the movements inside the same container. unless you want to process them separately.

Comment: Its working on my end 100%.
Thanks Mr. @Code Slinger for saving my time.

Comment: this is working on my end as well. Bloody fantastic!

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the receive event (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-receive).

Check out the resolution at the very bottom at http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3178.

Comment: Well then how do you handle sorting within the same list as well as a connected list? How do you know which one to honor?

Comment: @Jason: found the answer at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortables-update-callback-and-connectwith

Answer (score 3):

In order to call the update function only once, it is best to use the [stop event](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop), which indicates that the drag & drop has been finished. It will fire only once regardless if the drag&drop was within the same or connected lists.

```
$('.selector').sortable({
  stop: function(event, ui ) {
    ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using remove, receive and update to capture all changes and send them to the server as an array?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r2d3/p3J8z/

```
$(function(){

    /* Here we will store all data */
    var myArguments = {};   

    function assembleData(object,arguments)
    {       
        var data = $(object).sortable('toArray'); // Get array data 
        var step_id = $(object).attr("id"); // Get step_id and we will use it as property name
        var arrayLength = data.length; // no need to explain

        /* Create step_id property if it does not exist */
        if(!arguments.hasOwnProperty(step_id)) 
        { 
            arguments[step_id] = new Array();
        }   

        /* Loop through all items */
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) 
        {
            var image_id = data[i]; 
            /* push all image_id onto property step_id (which is an array) */
            arguments[step_id].push(image_id);          
        }
        return arguments;
    }   

    /* Sort images */
    $('.step').sortable({
        connectWith: '.step',
        items : ':not(.title)',
        /* That's fired first */    
        start : function( event, ui ) {
            myArguments = {}; /* Reset the array*/  
        },      
        /* That's fired second */
        remove : function( event, ui ) {
            /* Get array of items in the list where we removed the item */          
            myArguments = assembleData(this,myArguments);
        },      
        /* That's fired thrird */       
        receive : function( event, ui ) {
            /* Get array of items where we added a new item */  
            myArguments = assembleData(this,myArguments);       
        },
        update: function(e,ui) {
            if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
                 /* In case the change occures in the same container */ 
                 if (ui.sender == null) {
                    myArguments = assembleData(this,myArguments);       
                } 
            }
        },      
        /* That's fired last */         
        stop : function( event, ui ) {                  
            /* Send JSON to the server */
            $("#result").html("Send JSON to the server:<pre>"+JSON.stringify(myArguments)+"</pre>");        
        },  
    });
});
```

Here is the full explanation of the solution: 
http://r2d2.cc/2014/07/22/jquery-sortable-connectwith-how-to-save-all-changes-to-the-database/

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this. It's a bug in jQuery UI, see http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4872#comment:2

I commented to see if I can wake anyone up as to when there will be a fix. The joys of community driven development :P

Comment: This isn't really a bug, you're just binding to the wrong event.

Answer (score 0):

```
update: function(e, ui) {
    var draggedOut = this !== ui.item.parent()[0] && !$.contains(this, ui.item.parent()[0]);
    var draggedIn = ui.sender !== null;
    var sameList = !draggedOut && !draggedIn;

    if (sameList || draggedIn) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```