# Why does the update event in jquery sortable seem to run twice when testing for ui.sender

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI sortable to sort connected lists.  The update event appears to be running twice.

Here is the full sortable call:

```
$(".pageContent").sortable({
    handle: ".quesText",
    connectWith: ".pageContent",
    containment: "section",
    start: function(e, ui){
        ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
    },
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    opacity: 0.5,
    cursor: "move",
    cancel: "input, select, button, a, .openClose",
    update: function(e, ui){
        var thisItem = ui.item;
        var next = ui.item.next();
        var prev = ui.item.prev();

        var thisNumber = thisItem.find(".quesNumb");
        var nextNumber = next.find(".quesNumb");
        var prevNumber = prev.find(".quesNumb");

        var tn = parseInt(thisNumber.text());
        var nn = parseInt(nextNumber.text());
        var pn = parseInt(prevNumber.text());

        var quesNumbs = $(".quesNumb");

        var newItemId = thisItem.attr("id").replace(/_\d+$/, "_");

        //test if we are dragging top down
        if(ui.position.top > ui.originalPosition.top){
            quesNumbs.each(function(i){
                var thisVal = parseInt($(this).text());
                var grandparent = $(this).parent().parent();
                var grandId = grandparent.attr("id").replace(/_\d+$/, "_");
                if(thisVal > tn && (thisVal <= pn || thisVal <= (nn - 1))){
                    $(this).text(thisVal - 1 + ".");
                    grandparent.attr("id",grandId + (thisVal - 1));
                }
            });
            if(!isNaN(pn) || !isNaN(nn)){
                if(!isNaN(pn)){
                    //for some reason when there is a sender pn gets updated, so we check if sender exists
                    //only occurs sorting top down
                    if($.type(ui.sender) !== "null"){
                        var senderId = ui.sender.attr("id");
                        thisNumber.text(pn + 1 + ".");
                        thisItem.attr("id",senderId + "_" + (pn + 1));
                        alert(thisItem.attr("id"));
                    }
                    else {
                        thisNumber.text(pn + ".");
                        thisItem.attr("id",newItemId + pn);
                        alert(thisItem.attr("id"));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    thisNumber.text(nn - 1 + ".");
                }
            }
            else {
                   //something will happen here
            }
        }
        //otherwise we are dragging bottom up
        else {
            quesNumbs.each(function(i){
                var thisVal = parseInt($(this).text());
                if(thisVal < tn && (thisVal >= nn || thisVal >= (pn + 1))){
                    $(this).text(thisVal + 1 + ".");
                }
            });
            if(!isNaN(pn) || !isNaN(nn)){
                if(!isNaN(pn)){
                    thisNumber.text(pn + 1 + ".");
                }
                else {
                    thisNumber.text(nn + ".");
                }
            }
            else {
               //something will happen here
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the part that seems to run twice:

```
                if($.type(ui.sender) !== "null"){
                    var senderId = ui.sender.attr("id");
                    thisNumber.text(pn + 1 + ".");
                    thisItem.attr("id",senderId + "_" + (pn + 1));
                    alert(thisItem.attr("id"));
                }
                else {
                    thisNumber.text(pn + ".");
                    thisItem.attr("id",newItemId + pn);
                    alert(thisItem.attr("id"));
                }
```

I am expecting to only get one `alert` as `ui.sender` is `null` when the sorting stays inside the same list. When an item leaves a list to go to another then `ui.sender` will no longer be `null`.

The problem is I will get **2** alert messages when I move an item to a new list. Its as if ui.sender is set after the update function runs once then it runs through the update function again.  Obviously this is no good because I am overwriting data that should not necessarily be overwritten.

If that is the case how should I rewrite my code to avoid overwriting data?

**EDIT**

I believe the update event is called each time a list DOM is changed, not just the DOM in general. So for each list that has a DOM change the update runs.  When I move one item to a new list I am updating two lists.

So I guess the new question is: how do I rewrite this code knowing it will fire two times? Is there a combination of Receive and Remove events that could achieve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I did some investigating into each sortable event.  Here are my findings, listed in the order that they take place:

```
$(".pageContent").sortable({
    start: function(e,ui){
        //Before all other events
        //Only occurs once each time sorting begins
    },
    activate: function(e,ui){
        //After the start event and before all other events
        //Occurs once for each connected list each time sorting begins
    },
    change: function(e,ui){
        //After start/active but before over/sort/out events
        //Occurs every time the item position changes
        //Does not occur when item is outside of a connected list
    },
    over: function(e,ui){
        //After change but before sort/out events
        //Occurs while the item is hovering over a connected list
    },
    sort: function(e,ui){
        //After over but before out event
        //Occurs during sorting
        //Does not matter if the item is outside of a connected list or not
    },
    out: function(e,ui){
        //This one is unique
        //After sort event before all drop/ending events unless **see NOTE
        //Occurs, only once, the moment an item leaves a connected list
        //NOTE: Occurs again when the item is dropped/sorting stops 
        //--> EVEN IF the item never left the list
        //--> Called just before the stop event but after all other ending events
    },
    beforeStop: function(e,ui){
        //Before all other ending events: update,remove,receive,deactivate,stop
        //Occurs only once at the last possible moment before sorting stops
    },
    remove: function(e,ui){
        //After beforeStop and before all other ending events
        //Occurs only once when an item is removed from a list
    },
    receive: function(e,ui){
        //After remove and before all other ending events
        //Occurs only once when an item is added to a list
    },
    update: function(e,ui){
        //After receive and before all other ending events
        //Occurs when the DOM changes for each connected list
        //This can fire twice because two lists can change (remove from one
        //list but add to another)
    },
    deactivate: function(e,ui){
        //After all other events but before out (kinda) and stop
        //Occurs once for each connected list each time sorting ends
    },
    stop: function(e,ui){
        //After all other events
        //Occurs only once when sorting ends
    }
});
```

In solving my problem I just force the contents of my update function to only run once by wrapping it in an `if else` statement that checks for `ui.sender`. Basically it says if `ui.sender` does not exist then this is the first time through the update function and we should do the function, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Sorry but I think there is at least a glitch in the order of your events: the `stop` isn't the last event, it's the `update`. If I look at the [Dan Wellman's book «jQuery UI 1.8»](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849516525/the-sortables-component/ch13lvl1sec03) as reference to back me up, it is clear that the `stop` event occurs at the sort ends while the `update` event occurs when the sort has already ended and the DOM has changed... So `update` would be happening after `stop` and that's quite logical that way, don't you think?

Comment: @Cholesterol thanks for the input that does make more sense. But the information I ended up with here was through my testing of each event. I tested by calling console.log("whatever-this-event-is") when that event is fired. My findings were the update event sent out it's log before the stop event.

Comment: The source code never lies: [sortable.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/sortable.js#L1281) - the stop event is the last event

Comment: Thank you so much , i tried found why this is happening and finally solved it with your suggested solution .

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the answer here: [jquery Sortable connectWith calls the update method twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492828/jquery-sortable-connectwith-calls-the-update-method-twice)

You can combine the remove and receive and create an array which will hold changes and than post it to the server as JSON.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r2d3/p3J8z/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="step" id="step_1">
        <h2 class="title">Step 1</h2>
        <div class="image" id="image_10">Image 10</div>
        <div class="image" id="image_11">Image 11</div>
        <div class="image" id="image_12">Image 12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="step" id="step_2">
        <h2 class="title">Step 2</h2>
        <div class="image" id="image_21">Image 21</div>
        <div class="image" id="image_22">Image 22</div>
        <div class="image" id="image_23">Image 23</div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   $(function(){

        /* Here we will store all data */
        var myArguments = {};   

        function assembleData(object,arguments)
        {       
            var data = $(object).sortable('toArray'); // Get array data 
            var step_id = $(object).attr("id"); // Get step_id and we will use it as property name
            var arrayLength = data.length; // no need to explain

            /* Create step_id property if it does not exist */
            if(!arguments.hasOwnProperty(step_id)) 
            { 
                arguments[step_id] = new Array();
            }   

            /* Loop through all items */
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) 
            {
                var image_id = data[i]; 
                /* push all image_id onto property step_id (which is an array) */
                arguments[step_id].push(image_id);          
            }
            return arguments;
        }   

        /* Sort images */
        $('.step').sortable({
            connectWith: '.step',
            items : ':not(.title)',
            /* That's fired first */    
            start : function( event, ui ) {
                myArguments = {}; /* Reset the array*/  
            },      
            /* That's fired second */
            remove : function( event, ui ) {
                /* Get array of items in the list where we removed the item */          
                myArguments = assembleData(this,myArguments);
            },      
            /* That's fired thrird */       
            receive : function( event, ui ) {
                /* Get array of items where we added a new item */  
                myArguments = assembleData(this,myArguments);       
            },
            update: function(e,ui) {
                if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
                     /* In case the change occures in the same container */ 
                     if (ui.sender == null) {
                        myArguments = assembleData(this,myArguments);       
                    } 
                }
            },      
            /* That's fired last */         
            stop : function( event, ui ) {                  
                /* Send JSON to the server */
                $("#result").html("Send JSON to the server:<pre>"+JSON.stringify(myArguments)+"</pre>");        
            },  
        });
    });
```

Full explanation of the solution: 
http://r2d2.cc/2014/07/22/jquery-sortable-connectwith-how-to-save-all-changes-to-the-database/