# jQuery UI Sortable: order of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Does anyone know in which order the jQuery sortable events are being triggered?
I'm asking this because I had a problem with `stop` and `update`. It made more sense to me that `update` event would come after `stop` event but that was not the case.

Is this documented anywhere or did someone investigate this? I couldn't manage to find a proper list and I don't feel like looking through the code just yet.

Answer (score 8):

The order of events is:

**create** - Triggered when the sortable is created

**start** - Triggered when sorting starts

**activate** - Triggered for every connected list on drag start

**over** - Triggered when a sortable item is moved into a sortable list

**sort** - Triggered during sorting

**change** - Triggered during sorting, but only when DOM position has changed

**beforeStop** - Triggered before sorting stops, placeholder/helper

**update** - Triggered when stopped sorting and DOM position has changed

**deactivate** - Triggered before sorting stopped, propagated to all possible connected lists

**out** - Triggered when a sortable item is moved away from a sortable list

**stop** - Triggered when sorting has stopped

There are other events which can occur too:

receive/remove - Triggered when items are moved between lists

No idea why this isn't clearer on the jQueryUI site.

Note that, depending upon the event triggered, the ui arguments differs. It's worth looking at the API documentation to be clear what this is and to debug it.

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 1):

The stop event is the last to be fired. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15437655/3043811) to see all the events of a Jquery sortable element.

Answer (score 0):

From the current source code, `update` events are put into a queue:

```
delayedTriggers.push(function(event) {
    this._trigger("update", event, this._uiHash());
}); //Trigger update callback if the DOM position has changed
```

The queued events are then triggered between `beforestop` and `stop`:

```
this._trigger("beforeStop", event, this._uiHash());
for (i=0; i < delayedTriggers.length; i++) {
        delayedTriggers[i].call(this, event);
} //Trigger all delayed events
this._trigger("stop", event, this._uiHash());
```

Therefore, in the current implementation, `update` events will always be triggered before `stop` events.