# How use sortable jquery-ui feature to sort by drag and drop rows from two tables in the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two tables which are next to each other. Here is a short example of template:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a1</td>
            <td>a1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b1</td>
            <td>b1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a2</td>
            <td>a2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b2</td>
            <td>b2/td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So it looks like that:

```
|a1|a1|a2|a2|
|b1|b1|b2|b2|
```

My goal is to use sortable jquery-ui feature to sort by drag and drop rows of both tables in the same time. In other words - when user clicks for example cell from tabel1 then the whole row

```
|a1|a1|a2|a2|
```

should be draged and then droped while mouse up. **I don't need to drag and drop rows *between* two tables** - I need rows from two tables to be treated as one row while dragging - if this rows have the same position Y in its table.

Actually, the use case is that I have grid where I need to implement drag and drop rows. User can freeze some columns of the grid - then there are 2 tables- one for freezed columns and one for unfreezed - so there is actually one row but divided into 2 table. Here is an example of grid:
https://www.igniteui.com/grid/column-fixing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dragging rows between tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048496/dragging-rows-between-tables)

Comment: Take a look here: https://coursesweb.net/javascript/jquery-drag-drop-rows-between-two-similar-tables_cs or here: https://codepen.io/pixeline/pen/pJRyJX

Comment: I don't need to drag and drop rows between two tables - I need rows from two tables to be treated as one row while dragging - if this rows have the same position Y.

Comment: This can be done. First, how do you identify which in the sister table, to drag along with the selected row. Also should the reverse be true?

Comment: I have ids of these two tables to identify them. Yes, if I drop then the new order must be set. Actually, the use case is that I have grid where I need to implement drag and drop rows. User can freeze some columns of the grid - then there are 2 tables- one for freezed columns and one for unfreezed - so there is actually one row but divided into 2 tables.

Comment: @SigGP so it sounds like the relationship is built via table ID. If you need to freeze some rows, just disable them from Sort. I think you're making this overly complex. Also please update your example and include your current sortable code.

Comment: Not rows are freezed but columns. Here is sample of this grid: https://www.igniteui.com/grid/column-fixing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a good way to accomplish this. This also gets more difficult if you have a larger number of items. Basically, you perform sort on one table, and then when the sort is complete, move the corresponding item to the proper location in the second table.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#table1 tbody").sortable({
    handle: ".row-handle",
    items: "> tr",
    helper: function(e, item) {
      var index = item.index();
      item.data("right", $("#table2 tbody tr:eq(" + index + ")").clone());
      item.data("orig-index", index);
      $("#table2 tbody tr:eq(" + index + ")").fadeOut("fast");
      return item;
    },
    update: function(e, ui) {
      var row2 = ui.item.data("right");
      var index = ui.item.index();
      $("#table2 tbody tr").eq(ui.item.data("orig-index")).remove();
      switch (true) {
        case index == 0:
          console.log("First", index);
          $("#table2 tbody tr:eq(0)").before(row2);
          break;
        case index == $("#table2 tr").length:
          console.log("Last", index);
          $("#table2 tbody").append(row2);
          break;
        case index > 0 && index < $("#table2 tr").length:
          console.log("Mid", index);
          $("#table2 tbody tr").eq(index).before(row2);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="left ui-widget">
  <thead class="ui-widget-header">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="ui-widget-content">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical row-handle"></span></td>
      <td>Company 1</td>
      <td>Name 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical row-handle"></span></td>
      <td>Company 2</td>
      <td>Name 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical row-handle"></span></td>
      <td>Company 3</td>
      <td>Name 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table2" class="right ui-widget">
  <thead class="ui-widget-header">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 1</td>
      <td>Address 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 2</td>
      <td>Address 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 3</td>
      <td>Address 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Update**

Adjusted the `update` logic to work better. Moving an item multiple times now fixed.

---

This works pretty well on the first go, yet starts to encounter issues  with other sorts. I do not see a benefit to aligning two tables like this, for use with Sortable. You may want to consider if this is a necessary feature versus the sort function already built into your grid plugin.

Hope that helps.